# Node.JS event loop socket delayed or thread blocked

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with node.js when sending a lot of concurrent request. The problem is that sometimes it seems it puts some request at the end of the `event pool` and give me the response after some serious time (60 seconds+, normal is under 10 seconds).

The story goes like this, i have 3 scripts, a **CONSOLE**, a **SERVER** and 10 **CLIENTS**.

**console.js**

```
// sending message
client.connect(port, host, function(connect_socket)
{
    client.sendMessage(code:301,... some json-socket message ...);

    client.on('message', function(message)
    {
        if(message.code == 304)
        {
            console.log(... print data ...)
        }
    });
}
```

**server.js**

```
server = net.createServer(function(socket)
{
    socket = new JsonSocket(socket);

    socket.on('message', function(message)
    {
        if(message.code == 301)
        {
            var client_random = get_random_client();
            client_random.sendMessage(code:302,... some json-socket message ...);
        }

        if(message.code == 303)
        {
            var client_return = get_client_by_id(message.return_client_id);
            client_return.sendMessage(code:304,... some json-socket message ...);
        }
    });
    });

});
```

**client.js**

```
client.connect(port, host, function(connect_socket)
{
    client.on('message', function(message)
    {
        if(message.code == 302)
        {
            execute_command(message.data, function(result_command)
            {
                client.sendMessage(code:303,... some json-socket message (good or bad check) ...)
            });


        }
    });
}
```

Arhitecture concept, console sends message to server, server to a random client, client executes an external program and sends output back to server, server sends response back to the console and console prints it.

```
console.js => server.js => client.js => server.js => console.js
```

I open the server, clients are connecting no problem. I open the console and type the command, i get every time the response under 10 seconds.

Now, i made another `PHP` script that would simulate 600 requests per second. I do the same thing, open console, send command, and once every 10 runs (1 of 10), **the console waits**, waits and waits, and **after 60 seconds it gives me the result (10 was normal)**.

I made some debug and it seems that `server.js` **do not trigger message event** when reciving from `client.js` and somehow **puts it at the very end** of the `event pool`, but never forget it, runs eventually.

I have double check :

1. console.js every time sends message to server.js (always instant)
2. server.js every time sends message to client.js (always instant)
3. client.js every time sends message to server.js (always instant)
4. [server.js do not fire the event `message` event instant, and put it
   on the  very end of the `event pool` ]
5. server.js every time sends message to client.js (always instant)

Also i have checked for the possible **I/O main thread block**, everything is fine. All operations are async, no sync functions.

It is that kind of bug that sometime it is manifesting, sometimes not. Like after a `console.js` waiting, you can open another terminal and `console.js` and send messages and see how it responds right away. As i already told, it is like a probability of 1 from 10.

How can i solve this? I had made a lot of debugging.

Comment: What OS are you using? Socket exhaustion is a known problem for OSX and has symptoms like you describe. Linux and Windows are not affected.

Comment: Linux, Ubuntu (80% of servers) and debian (20% of servers), it is looking like from time to time the `socket.on('message')` is not triggering right away, it is delayed to the end of the `event queue`